# Python winsound, ASYNC flag not working?

Tags: python, winsound

I'm using python 3.5 and I'm trying to play a sound while continuing right away with my script; according to https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html the flag "winsound.SND_ASYNC" should be the way to go. However the following doesn't produce any sound:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Bob/Sounds/sound.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Interesting enough if I change the flag to "winsound.SND_FILENAME the sound is played:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Bob/Sounds/sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Any ideas why the async flag doesn't work?

Comment: try to replace `C:/Users/Bob/Sounds/sound.wav` by `C:\Users\Bob\Sounds\sound.wav`

Comment: It seems that you have to use two flags like, `winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Bob/Sounds/sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)` [_The sound parameter may be a filename, audio data as a string, or None. Its interpretation depends on the value of flags, **which can be a bitwise ORed combination** of the constants described below_](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound)

Comment: @Himal absolutely correct, and big thank you; it was driving me nuts :)

Comment: Glad it worked. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound),

> The sound parameter may be a filename, audio data as a string, or None. Its interpretation depends on the value of flags, **which can be a bitwise ORed combination** of the constants described below

Something like follows:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Bob/Sounds/sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody will google this with reason, that particularly `winsound.SND_ASYNC` flag is not working in combination with `winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC`, and everything working without it, just for `winsound.SND_FILENAME` - sometimes the problem is, when calling winsound at the end of your script, it will not be play with async flag, cause script already stopped, so it stops anything else with async flag. Check this out:

```
import winsound
import time


def wavsound(asynced=True):
    flags = winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC if asynced else winsound.SND_FILENAME
    winsound.PlaySound(r"path_to_your_wav_file", flags)


# it would or would not play at the end of your python script if:
wavsound(asynced=True)  # play if this line uncommented and wavsound(asynced=False) commented
# wavsound(asynced=False) # not play if this line uncommented and wavsound(asynced=True) commented

# time.sleep(2) # if uncomment this - play first 2 seconds and then cutoff with asynced=True
```