# Winsound Async not playing sound

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

i know this question has been answered, but the answer didn't work for me. [Python winsound, ASYNC flag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128232/python-winsound-async-flag-not-working)

I'm trying to play a sound file using winsound asynchronously, but if I use

```
winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav",winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

It won't play the sound, but if I use

```
winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav",winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

It will, but i need it to be asynchronously so i can stop the audio if needed.

Is there something i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Make sure your program is still running after you call `winsound.PlaySound`. Playback stops as soon as your program exits.

Comment: @sal thanks, my program was finishing after i just called `winsound.PlaySound`, it is correct now.